# Could not create Facebook Object

Tags: facebook, firefox

At my index.php I create an Facebook Object and use it to get the UserID.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
'cookie' => true
));
```

I also make some API Requests and everything is fine.

Now I switch to another subpage (events.php - which is mostly the same as index.php).
But here I can't access the USER ID with

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

It's always 0. As I said, the commands to create the Facebook Object is the same - only another webpage as index.php.

//edit - just found out that it's not only a Firefox problem as I thought before.

Comment: am I correct in understanding that chrome DOES give the userid?  Given that this is serverside it seems browser independent.

Comment: Ok, just found out that chrome doesn't give the userid neither.

Comment: Do you include the facebook.php source again? Can you give us a sample page on events.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are passing the $facebook session variable to your new page (events.php). A return of 0 means that there is no logged in user, and therefore the session hasn't been instantiated.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/

Here are some more helpful docs explaining how to get the current user/session using the Facebook PHP SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/

Comment: I couldn't get the facebook session - I do this with $facebook->getSession() right? But it doesn't give anything back.

Comment: No, $facebook->getUser() will get the session.

Comment: $facebook->getUser() gets only the UserID.

Comment: Yes. A return of 0 indicates there is no active session (and therefore no logged in user). "$facebook" is the "session variable", to speak, and "->getUser()" is an action on the variable proving if it is active.

Comment: Ok, than I guess the problem is to transfer the $facebook session to the new page. Do you have an Idea how to do this?

Comment: Either by a PHP function (passing a variable) or you can even use a PHP session http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm